# How to set the property as lazyloading in fluent-hibernate with auto-mapping?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am using auto-mapping with flent-hibernate for mapping. I would like if there is a way to set the reference property to be as 'lazy-loading' using IConvention or similar, rather than using separate mapping class?

Comment: Isn't lazy loaded the default?

Comment: yes, i believe so. but then, there will be times when we need to on/off lazy loading.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, i believe that lazy is the default behaviour.
you can test it quite easily-

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestLazyLoading()
        {
            Airport firstObject = null;
            using (ISession session = this.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    ObjectDAO dao = new ObjectDAO(session, CurrentUser);
                    firstObject = dao.GetObject();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            Assert.IsFalse(NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(firstObject.Children));

        }
```

if you want to specify explicitly lazy / eager, use the following inside your MappingOverride class:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Employees)
                //.Not
                .LazyLoad()
                ;
```

Answer (score 1):

To adjust automappings you can use `IAutoMappingOverride<SomeEntity>`. You can change there exact property that you need